# Trouble using Find/Replace with a regex

Tags: regex, textpad

I have the below sample text

```
in front xxxx extra xxxx
```

that I am trying to convert so "http" starts on a new line:

```
in front
xxxx
xxxx
```

I am using TEXTPAD with regular expressions checked in the FIND/REPLACE window.

I have tried using the `/n` command, but all it does is add the `/n` to the from of `xxxx` in the original line.

How do I use FIND/REPLACE with regular expressions to do what I want?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Having said this, what is the relationship between "http" and `xxxx` in your question?  Your question remains unclear primarily because this does not make much sense.  On the other hand, your question may also very well be closed because it seems to be due to a simple typo (per @hwnd's answer); but it would still be best to edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

You have your syntax confused and backwards. A newline sequence is `\n` not "/n" ...